# Subversion post-commit with different user

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I've installed subversion and have the following setup:

Repo:
`/home/svn/tester (apache:apache)`

The site is:
`/var/www/tester (tester:tester)`

I've checked out the tester repo to `/var/www/tester`

in the `/home/svn/tester/hooks/post-commit` I have:
`sudo -u tester /usr/bin/svn update /home/tester --username aaa --password bbb`

What I am trying to do is keep the owners of the files in `/home/svn/tester = apache`
and the owner of files in `/var/www/tester = tester`

I have added to `/etc/sudoers`:
`tester ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/svn`

I've commented out requiretty in `/etc/sudoers`:
`#Defaults    requiretty`

Once I run the commit I receive the following message (in tortoisesvn):

```
Commit failed (details follow):
MERGE of '/svn/tester': 200 OK (https://[site name])
```

Am I going about this the correct way? If so how can I get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

You've configured your repository below the normal web stuff.

```
/var/_www_/tester
```

That won't work: SVN requests some DAV stuff, but it only gets normal answers.
That's why `200 OK` is actually an error in this case.

Move your repository out of the `www` tree and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was actually able to get it working in /var/www/tester just needed to have 'apache' instead of 'tester' in sudoers file